# How can I use dockerfile to install any software which should be usable in the host?

Tags: docker, installation

As far as I understand, a docker container can be thought of as an isolated environment (not completely though) from the host. Everything happening inside the docker container does not affect the host.

Is it possible to install some software using a docker container, where the installed software should be usable outside of the docker container (i.e. host)?
If yes, how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly understand, Docker is an isolation environment: the host system can't directly access programs or anything else in the container filesystem, and containers can't directly install software on the host.

There are a variety of established packaging mechanisms (Debian packages, MacOS Homebrew scripts, tar files, ...) that can be used to install software directly on the host.  Docker can be really inconvenient for some common use cases!  If it doesn't match what you need (an interactive GUI application, other tooling that needs to be accessible from a command line) a native package or a tar file might work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, To go about that;

1. List your docker containers:
   $ sudo docker ps
2. Login into your docker container:
   $ sudo docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/sh
3. Use terminal and install the software and make sure you know the port at which the software is running at, for example port 6770 and mapped it to the port in the host machine.
4. Exit the docker container
5. Open port of the host machine to which you want to access the app installed.